# node-red - API response caching

Tags: node.js, rest, caching, node-red

I am writing an API with the `http in` node in Node-RED. For `GET` requests for certain paths, I would like to cache the response so that, there is no further execution of the flow. I came across to two Node-RED packages [cache](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-cache) and [global-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-globalcache). However, they don't seem to caching the API responses.

How can I cache API responses in node-red?

Comment: The first can probably be used (to some extent) to do what you want, the second appears to be related to a network attached IR device. Edit the question to show how you tried to use the first node, because as it stands this question is probably a bit too broad.

Comment: @hardillb I haven't used the `node-red-contrib-cache` package because, I am thinking, the `HTTP In` node may have to change too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`node-red-contrib-cache`](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-cache) doesn't automatically cache the response but you can create this logic yourself like so:

[image]

First you need to set `msg.topic` which will be the cache key. Here I used `msg.req.url` expression:

[image]

Next you need input **Cache** node that will try to get the response from cache. It will propagate `msg.payload` and if nothing was found in cache it will return `null`.

This is where you use **Switch** node to branch out:

[image]

If it was `null` you go to the node that will create the response (in this case a function) and then use output **Cache** node to store it for later and send it to **http response** node.

If it wasn't `null` just pass it straight to the **http response** node.

You probably need to adjust the cache key and the TTL.